# The overload is ambigous

Tags: c++, c++11

I am doing some C++ interview questions (for fun). I found the following:

> According to C++11 standard, what is the output of this program?
>
> ```
> #include <iostream> 
>
> void f(int){std::cout << 1;}
> void f(unsigned){std::cout << 2;}
>
> int main()
> {
>  f(-2.5);
> }
> ```
>
> The answer is that there is a **compilation error**, because the overload is ambigous.

But why? Is it not clear for the compiler that -2.5 is a signed `int`, so it outputs 1?

Comment: `-2.5` is a `double`, not a signed `int`.

Comment: The compiler is capable of making either conversion. Why would it favor one or the other?

Comment: `-2.5` is of type `double`.    The conversions to `int` or `unsigned` are both equally valid under rules of the language (i.e. the compiler has no reason to select one over the other).   The selection of which function to call therefore involves ambiguity.

Comment: @Peter the conversions are equally ranked for  *overload resolution ranking*.  Converting `-2.5` to `unsigned` is not valid under other rules (the floating-to-integer rules) but that is not taken into account at the overload resolution stage.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Of course! I'm ashamed...

Answer (score 0):

Well . You are trying to call the function with a floating point number ...
try using integer values...
The Program would work if you used `f(-2)` instead of `f(-2.5)` but as [@Mark Ranson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5987/mark-ransom) pointed out " An integer literal is always `int` unless you add additional qualifiers".
What he meant was that even if you used f(-2) it would give the same result as f(2).. which obviously renders the overload useless.

Comment: Strangely, `f(2)` will produce the same output. An integer literal is always `int` unless you add additional qualifiers.

Comment: @MSalters it's not ambiguous. The answer was edited, it used to suggest `f(-2)` worked and I was pointing out that it didn't matter if you used a positive or negative integer. Once that was removed my comment was out of context.